# What is difference between rpm -F and rpm -U?

Tags: unix, rpm

I was going through the man page of `rpm` but could get the exact difference between `rpm -F` and `rpm -U`.
Can anyone please help me out in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-F|--freshen` only installs an update for packages that were already installed on the system. So

```
rpm -U already-installed-package.2.0.rpm
rpm -F already-installed-package.2.0.rpm
```

are equivalent, but

```
rpm -U not-installed-package.2.0.rpm # will install
rpm -F not-installed-package.2.0.rpm # won't install
```

are not.

from the man page:

> rpm {-U|--upgrade} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...
>
> ```
>    This upgrades or installs the package currently installed to a newer version.  This is the same as install, except all other
> ```
>
> version(s) of the package are removed after the new package is
>   installed.
>
> ```
>    rpm {-F|--freshen} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...
>
>    This will upgrade packages, but only ones for which an earlier version is installed.
> ```